# spring security got 403 instead of 404

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a Spring boot application configured with the following security context:

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
    .addFilterAfter(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class)
```

When a client requests an existing resource, the `jwtAuthenticationFilter` does his job and the client gets the true response.
But when a client requests a no-existing resource, the `jwtAuthenticationFilter` is triggered before Spring realizes that the resource does not exist. So he gets 403 error instead of a 404.

How can I fix that ?